# Embed Javascript into a batch file to clear Internet Explorer SSL State

Tags: javascript, batch-file, embed

I want to create a batch file that will clear the internet Explorer SSL State. So far, the only method I know of to clear the SSL state is through JavaScript. I want to embed the JavaScript into the batch file.

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>  
    document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");  
</script>
```

I've tried

```
@set @junk=1 /*
@echo off
cscript //nologo //E:jscript %0 %*
goto :eof
*/

document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");
```

doesn't work

Comment: try `cscript /nologo /E:jscript "%~f0" %*`. `%~f0` is the full path/name of the script.

Comment: I just tried that and, it's still not working, it won't clear the SSL state.

Comment: I showed you how to actually execute the java-part. I get a Java Runtime Error `document is not defined`, but I can't help you with that (I don't speak Java).

Comment: Thank you for your help, Javascript works when executing from internet explorer when executing from the batch file no internet explorer is defined so we get the error document is not defined. I'll do more research, again thank you for your help.